# add sweet alert to LinkButton event

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton, sweetalert

i am wondering if this any way to combine sweet alert with asp.net linkbutton. for example i have this button to delete row from gridview and i want to fire up the sweet alert style

my code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-sm" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item?');" runat="server"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></asp:LinkButton>
```

and this is the sweet alert example:

```
swal({   title: "Are you sure?",   text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",   type: "warning",   showCancelButton: true,   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   closeOnConfirm: false }, function(){   swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not figured a way to utilize the gridview rowcommand function, so instead pass the id value to the SweetAlert confirm function and post back through a hidden button.

```
function myConfirm(msgID) {
        $("#<%=hfMsgID.ClientID%>").val(msgID);
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this message!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, function () {
            $("#<%=btnDeleteMsg.ClientID%>").click();
        });

    }


<asp:HiddenField ID="hfMsgID" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteMsg" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" />
```

In the code behind, you can execute from the hidden button's click event. Just access the hidden field value for the id and then reload/rebind after execution.